# Can't set focus on my Subform in Access - error 2465 (can not find the field '|1' referred to in your expression)

Tags: vba, ms-access, setfocus, subform

Recently I am messing ( a lot) around with setting focus to my subform. For some reason I can't set the focus to my subform and it keeps giving me the error: can `not find the field '|1' referred to in your expression` I tried multiple ways to set the focus but all of them won't work.

What I tried so far:

- `Forms("frmArtikelSubInkoopHistorie").SetFocus`  **(Set focus directly to the subform)**
- `[Forms]![frmArtikelen].[frmArtikelSubInkoopHistorie].SetFocus` **(Set focus to the subform with reference to it's main form)**
- `[Forms]![frmArtikelen].[frmArtikelSubInkoopHistorie].SetFocus`

  `[Forms]![frmArtikelen].[frmArtikelSubInkoopHistorie].[Form].[Tekst33].SetFocus` **(First set focus to the subform itself and then setting focus to the subforms control)**

First I tried to set the focus on the `Load event` of the `main form` but this caused the error as well.

Then I tried to set the focus in the `load event` of the `subform` itself but this event never gets fired.

Lastly I tried (and this is where I left off) to set the focus in the `change event` of my `tab control` (the subform resides in one of the tabs):

```
Private Sub TabbestEl91_Change()

On Error GoTo eri

Select Case TabbestEl91
    Case 3  'Inkoop Historie

    'Forms("frmArtikelSubInkoopHistorie").SetFocus
    [Forms]![frmArtikelen].[frmArtikelSubInkoopHistorie].SetFocus
    [Forms]![frmArtikelen].[frmArtikelSubInkoopHistorie].[Form].[Tekst33].SetFocus

  End Select

eri:
MsgBox (Err.Number)
MsgBox (Err.description)

End Sub
```

I guess the focusing failing because the subform isn't loaded yet on the moment it sets the focus, this is just an assumption though and I thought this would be fixed if I would set the focus in the tab change (the subform should be loaded by then).

P.s. found multiple posts on this subject but non of them fixed my problem or were totally different than mine.

Any ideas to get this fixed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following syntax:

```
Forms![frmArtikelen]![frmArtikelSubInkoopHistorie].Form![Tekst33].SetFocus
```

Note the exclamation marks that have been added. Also, it may sound counter intuitive but I believe that when a form loads, the subform loads before the mainform.

I don't understand at what point you actually want to apply the setfocus, in order to understand where the event should go.

Are you aware that you don't need VBA to select the tab index of the subform to 0? and then set the tab index within the subform so that `tekst33` is 0?

Comment: I use following syntax from Open event of main form: `Me.frmArtikelSubInkoopHistorie.SetFocus` first and then `Me.frmArtikelSubInkoopHistorie.Form.Tekst33.SetFocus`. Possible different combinations of referencing, but order should be like this.

Comment: @LiamH Thank you! Will try it out in a bit. The point of setting the focus has to do with something entirely different. I need to loop though the subforms records (movelast, movefirst) because the subform is causing a suspended state in my SQL server (got linked tables). But to loop through the subform records it has to have focus (else I am getting an error as well).

Comment: @Nicolas Could you avoid the focussing issue by creating a recordset on a query in the main form, looping through this recordset (which would be identical to your subform query). Then use a requery on the subform if you have made changes?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to set focus on my subform date after a new record is created.
Sequential code to set focus on the subform then the subform field might work for you:

1. from parent form setfocus on the subform first

Me.SF_DRL_Scheduling.SetFocus

2. then point to last record of the subform (even if filter is active)

DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast '

3. finally refer to the field in subform

Me.SF_DRL_Scheduling.Form.DrScDte.SetFocus

Answer (score -1):

On Error Resume Next

'For second time doesn't run code below and raises error, so we need On Error Resume Next above. but with one more time else again run it code, there is ok runing all codes and process below

```
Me.frmArtikelSubInkoopHistorie.SetFocus

Forms![frmArtikelen]![frmArtikelSubInkoopHistorie].Form![Tekst33].SetFocus
```